# How to update rows with the same foreign key without updating them all

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I'm working on my university project and I need some help about Oracle database.

I have two tables `USERFORM` and `ACADEMICTRAINING`.

**USERFORM**

```
Name           Null?    Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
USER_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER(5)    
FIRSTNAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
LASTNAME       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60) 
BORN_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
PHONE          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
ACCESSPASSWORD NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
```

**ACADEMICTRAINING**

```
Name           Null?    Type          
-------------- -------- ------------- 
AT_ID          NOT NULL NUMBER(5)     
START_DATE     NOT NULL DATE          
END_DATE       NOT NULL DATE          
INSTITUTION    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100) 
COURSE         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(70)  
AT_DESCRIPTION          VARCHAR2(200)
```

`AT_ID` is a foreign key that references `USERFORM` on `USER_ID` column.

I would like to know if there's some way to `UPDATE` one single row without affecting other rows with the same foreign key.

Comment: To update only 1 row you need a primary key(or set of columns) to target only 1 row. However, if you do not have such combination in your DB and this is only 1 time excercise, I guess that is doable using the tool you are using such as SQL Developer.

Comment: That's good to know, I need a DB with more growth capabbilities, I will work on your recommendation, thank you!

Comment: Which table and columns do you need to update, and what is stopping you doing that exactly? Also, how does PL/SQL code come into this?

Comment: I need to update `ACADEMICTRAINING` on all the columns. I can update, but, if I update a row with a foreign key which is being used on other row, both update, and that isn't good for me. Basically, now I'm using `UPDATE academictraining SET ~columns and values~ WHERE at_id = userform.user_id`. That foreign key means that an user can have one or more academic training on his profile, but I need to control the row which he is updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 Update ACADEMICTRAINING
 set COURSE = 'BSC.CS'
 where AT_ID = (select USER_ID
                from USERFORM
                where FIRSTNAME = 'Ali'
                and LASTNAME = 'Ahmed'
                and PHONE = '44425183658558' );
```

Comment: Still updating all rows that have the same foreign key, I guess that don't have any diferences of doing this or doing `WHERE AT_ID = USERFORM.USER_ID`

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is messed up, which is what is confusing you.  Why are you naming a *user* column `AT_ID`.  Also the foreign keys are not declared.  A better approach is:

```
CREATE TABLE ACADEMICTRAINING (
    USER_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES USERFORM(USER_ID),
    START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,         
    END_DATE  DATE NOT NULL       
    INSTITUTION VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
    COURSE VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL 
    AT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200) 
);
```

You really want to have a primary key in the table.  Under most circumstances, I would recommend an auto-incrementing primary key.  But that is hard to do automatically in Oracle prior to Oracle 12.  Such a column should be called something like `ACADEMICTRAINING_ID`.

Instead, you really want a unique key.  I don't know what fits your requirements, but let's say the first two columns cannot be repeated (more columns might be involved).  Then:

```
ALTER TABLE ACADEMICTRAINING ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_ACADEMICTRAINING_2
    UNIQUE (USER_ID, START_DATE);
```

All that said, what you need in your `UPDATE` is a way to choose *which* row.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE ACADEMICTRAINING
    SET . . .
    WHERE USER_ID = :USER_ID AND START_DATE = :START_DATE;
```

If you had a primary key, it would look like:

```
UPDATE ACADEMICTRAINING
    SET . . .
    WHERE ACADEMICTRAINING_ID = :ACADEMICTRAINING_ID;
```